# Excel =large formula - dynamic array

Tags: excel-formula

I have a date dropdown on Sheet1  (=Sheet1!B5)

This helps populate Sheet1 with values from Sheet ‘Data’. I have been using Vlookup with Match formula for others. (=VLOOKUP(G20,Data!A:Z,MATCH(Sheet1!$B$5,Data!$3:$3,0),FALSE))

But Im stuck on how to use =Large formula in same way. I am trying to take top 5 values per day – using date dropdown. I can’t figure out how to dynamically change the column letter in the array =large formula to take correct values corresponding date.

So far I can directly take top 5 from column C - =LARGE(Data!C44:C65,1)

But I want this work for column D onwards..

[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: So a link to a picture would help us visualize what you are asking.

Comment: Cant seem to add images

Comment: I fixed your picture, but I think we need to see what your Data sheet looks like as well.

Comment: That is the data sheet.  How can I dynamically amend =LARGE(Data!C44:C65,1) so, if references correct column depending on date selected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this formula:

```
=LARGE(INDIRECT("Data!" &ADDRESS(44,MATCH(1E+99,44:44)) & ":" & ADDRESS(65,MATCH(1E+99,44:44))),1)
```

It will find the right most column with numbers.

Or this one uses your match from the vlookup to choose the column:

```
=LARGE(INDIRECT("Data!" & ADDRESS(44,MATCH(Sheet1!$B$5,Data!$3:$3,0)) & ":" & ADDRESS(65,MATCH(Sheet1!$B$5,Data!$3:$3,0))),1)
```

Comment: Thanks Scott, this references c44:c65 of Sheet1. To reference sheet 'Data' - I amaneded to **=LARGE(INDIRECT("Data!" & ADDRESS(44,MATCH(Sheet1!$B$5,Data!$3:$3,0)) & ":" & ADDRESS(65,MATCH(Sheet1!$B$5,Data!$3:$3,0))),1)**

Comment: @Canuhelp Yeah I missed changing that.